# what is wrong with 'this.setState'

Tags: reactjs

Please i have this problem with my react class,i'm trying to update my state but i'm get this error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" ..I have tried every solution online,but no luck

here is the code

```
export default class PageBackground extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state={
                lat         :'nothing',
                longi       :''
            };
            this.getLocation=this.getLocation.bind(this);
            }


        componentWillMount() {
            this.getLocation();
        }
        getLocation () {

            fetch('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
             .then((res)=>res.json())
             .then(function (objec){this.setState({lat:objec.latitude,longi:objec.longitude});})
             .catch((err)=>console.log("didn't connect to App",err))
             console.log(this.state.lat)
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <p>{this.state.lat}</p>
                )
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you get the console logs?

Comment: I think `this` is in the context of the function. maybe you should try `that=this` and `that.setState`

Comment: There is litterally a million duplicates of this very error. I'm surprised you haven't been able to find any of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `function () { ... }` syntax won't maintain the `this` reference from the context. Use an arrow function instead:

```
then(() => {
    this.setState({lat: objec.latitude, longi: objec.longitude})
})
```

Another option is to add `.bind(this)` after `function () { }`.

Or, just save `this` to a local variable and use it inside the function:

```
var self = this;
fetch('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
         .then((res)=>res.json())
         .then(function (objec){self.setState({lat:objec.latitude,longi:objec.longitude});})
         .catch((err)=>console.log("didn't connect to App",err))
         console.log(this.state.lat)
```

However, arrow functions were introduced exactly for this kind of problems.

Comment: thank you very much.This worked but i want to know why? i read the arrow function doesn't work well with 'this' why is this situation different?

Comment: and why do we even have to bind all methods in we create in es6 class in our constructor?

Comment: @JohnAnisere The answer to the first question is that arrow functions capture `this` from the surrounding code, therefore you don't have to bind `this` to them manually. They work in the way you would expect. The other question is more complicated. You are talking about the problem when class methods are used as "loose" (first class) functions. The methods are not bound automatically to their instance and must be bound manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
   getLocation () {
            var self = this;
            fetch('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
             .then(function (objec) {
               console.log(objec);
               self.setState({lat: objec.latitude, longi: objec.longitude})
             })
            .catch(function (error) {
               console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, you are trying to accesss `this` in a different scope.

Whenever we pass a `function() {}` as a callback it creates it's own scope.
Use arrow function's instead.

```
() => { 'your code here'; }
```

Arrow functions share the scope of its parent.

```
getLocation = () => {
    fetch('https://freegeoip.net/json/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((objec) => {
            this.setState({ lat: objec.latitude, longi: objec.longitude });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("didn't connect to App", err));
    console.log(this.state.lat);
}
```